# Android Play Store minimum target API 26

Tags: android, google-play, android-api-levels

When I try to upload my signed APK with target API level 23 I receive this error:

Your app's current target API level is 23, but the minimum target API level must be 26 to ensure that the app is based on the latest APIs optimized for security and good performance. Change the target API level of your app to at least 26.

But if I rebuild with target API level 26 I receive this error:

This version cannot be implemented because it does not allow existing users to upgrade to the latest APKs added.

How can I ignore users upgrade?

Comment: The minimum target SDK version is 26, not the minimum min SDK version.

You can still set your minimum as low as 14, the requirement for targeting API 26.

Comment: `android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.outlocks"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26 // place here 26, not in the compile
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

Comment: Please post the solution as an accepted answer instead of editing the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

This version cannot be implemented because it does not allow existing users to update to the latest APKs added.

It was caused by a lower version code than the one currently in production and was unrelated to the API version. I have increased the version number and I can safely use the API level 26